# how to set log4j.configuration system variable in WebSphere 7?

Tags: log4j, websphere, ear

I have a Java EE 5 web app I'm deploying to WebSphere 7 as an EAR file.

I want my log4j configuration to be external to the EAR file so I can tweak log content when needed without needing to rebuild and redeploy the EAR file.

My understanding is I can specify the location of my log4j.properties file by setting a 
"system variable" called log4j.configuration. (ex. log4j.configuration=c:/log4j.properties)

My question is, how do I set this system variable in the WebSphere 7 admin console?

Browsing around I see there is `Environment > WebSphere Variables`, but that doesn't look right because that would be setting a variable for the entire server.  I'm guessing I want to set a system variable just for my application EAR file.

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Rob

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `log4j.configuration` property is a Java Virtual Machine system property. You can load this property by adding it to the end of your application server's list of generic JVM arguments. This is done in the WebSphere Console by navigating through the following:

`Servers > Application servers > [app server name] > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine`

Under Generic JVM arguments, add the following:

`-Dlog4j.configuration=file:C:/log4j.properties`

Click `Apply` at the bottom of this page, and save your changes.  This will require a restart of the application server to take effect.

Comment: Thanks, but this means there's one log4j.configuration for all apps on the server, correct?  I would have thought I could have one config file for my specific application.  Is that possible?

Comment: You are correct; this would apply everywhere. If you want application-level Log4J settings, you'll have to package a `log4j.properties` file within each application, and remove the `log4j.configuration` system property.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use shared library for an application and put your log4j.xml there.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution to assign to each EAR or WAR an external log4j.xml configuration file:

1. I extracted the log4j.xml from our EAR, Zipped this lone XML into a JAR file. Placed it on the server in a path accessible by WebSphere,
2. Create a Shared Library (WebSphere > Environment > Shared Libraries) mapping the classpath to this archive. Make sure to select "Use an isolated class loader for this shared library" or you'd have to assign reference for each module of your application rather than just the parent EAR.
3. Assigning the reference within our EAR
   (Application -> ApplicationType -> WebSphere enterprise applications -> EAR NAME -> Shared library references -> SELECT YOUR EAR -> Reference shared libraries -> SELECT THE LOG4J CONFIGURATION JAR) and ADD IT.
4. Restart the application

I used this way to assign a specific external log4j configuration file to each WAR in an an EAR. 
[Here](https://thequirksofit.blogspot.com/search?q=log4j%20) you can find the original solution.

Answer (score 0):

### How to point Log4j.xml(not log4j2.xml) to external file

For Log4J (not Log4J2) in websphere 8.5 in Linux OS, please a custom properties  under Servers > Application servers > [app server name] > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine.
property name: **log4j.configuration** property value : **file:/xyz/abc/def/config/log4j.xml**

NB: You don't need to append -D if you do it from custom properties. But if you give it under  Generic JVM arguments use this:
**-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/xyz/abc/def/config/log4j.xml** -Dlog4j.debug
Each property must be separated by space. I added debug logs for Log4J itself to see from where it is picking the log4J.xml file.