# Changing Log4j logger level via WAS console

Tags: logging, log4j, websphere

Is it possible to change the Log4j logger level via WAS console? 
If its possible can somebody please provide the steps for doing the same?

The following steps were tried,

After logging into WAS server go to Troubleshooting > Logs and trace > server1 > Change log detail levels
Click on the runtime tab.
In Change log detail levels section, replace the content with *=warning
With the above settings we expected to see only error and warnings in the dev server log files but, still we were getting all the logs.

Comment: How do you have log4j configured to write to the WAS logs? I'm guessing maybe you have your application using a Console appender? I don't believe, though, that there is any way to control that from the WAS tracing settings. Also, just to be certain, please indicate what version of WAS you're using as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set log4j.configuration system variable in WebSphere 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828582/how-to-set-log4j-configuration-system-variable-in-websphere-7)

Comment: To be able to change log level from the console your application has to use standard JUL logging.